# Why won't read-line block?

Tags: clojure

Why won't read-line block in the following instance?

Here's what happens when I lein run the program. I never get to enter a value.

```
Enter rover's moves LMMRM 
Enter rover's moves LMMRM 

(defn prompt-for-rover-moves
    []
    (do
        (println "Enter rover's moves LMMRM ")
        (read-line)
    ))

(defn -main 
    [& args]
    (do
        (let [grid-dim-in [0 5]
              mr1-pos     [\N 2 4]
              mr2-pos     [\N 1 5]
              mr1-movs    (prompt-for-rover-moves)
              mr2-movs    (prompt-for-rover-moves)]

            (reset! grid-dim grid-dim-in)
            (reset! mr1-id {:mr1 mr1-pos})
            (reset! mr2-id {:mr2 mr2-pos})

            (.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr1-id mr1-movs)))
            (.start (Thread. (rover-thread mr2-id mr2-movs))))))
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the `do` forms, the body of a function is an implicit `do`.

Comment: I tried your prompt-for-rover-moves function alone in the repl and it works for me.

Comment: This is lein repl. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it as a standalone Java app and it should work fine.

I've had the same problem running in the REPL and never came up with a decent solution.

Comment: My problem now, which I need to take up with the leininngen folks is the lein jar has no main in it, so I need to look at the lein tutorial.